# Is simultaneity independent to reference frame?

Tags: time, relativity

Imagine two events happening simultaneously with respect to my frame of reference. Is this possible to have a reference frame to which the events are observed NOT to be simultaneous?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity

Comment: If the two events are not at the same location, then in any frame of reference moving with respect to your frame the events will not be simultaneous.